# Obtain key value in for each in Javascript like PHP

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

I can do this in PHP:

```
foreach ($array as $pos=>$value) {
    ....
}
```

but I don't know how to do that in `Javascript` or `Jquery`. I want to use that $pos.

Comment: in Vanilla JS: [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for ordered arrays, or [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Range = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10];

$.each( Range, function( index , value ) {
       console.log( value );
});
```

## **Documentatión for this method:**

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

see this example ,hope it helps you

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
       alert(index);
       alert(value);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a great each() function

```
$.each(obj.Data,function(key,widget){
    alert(key); //Alerts ID (the key of the JSON Object)
    alert(widget.ID); //Alert the value of ID
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/each/